# npx prisma generate giving, `failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain` in Docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, express, npm, prisma

`RUN npx prisma generate` throwing error while building a docker image.

#12 1.036 Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/6b0aef69b7cdfc787f822ecd7cdc76d5f1991584/linux-arm64-openssl-3.0.x/libquery_engine.so.node.gz.sha256 failed, reason: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

##### `.npmrc`

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18

RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY package*.json ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
COPY .env ./

RUN npm install
RUN npx prisma generate.  

COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


EXPOSE 3001

CMD [ "node", "dist/index.js" ]
```

##### error

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing your network and check if you get the same error?

If you're running this in a corporate or otherwise controlled environment, it's possible that there's a proxy or firewall that's intercepting HTTPS connections and replacing the certificates with its own, which could be self-signed.

Comment: yes, it's the same issue, thanks @NurulSundarani you saved my days.